# Value Binding problem on input text generated by *NgFor

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, ngfor

When trying to *ngFor over an array in angular to generate input text element and bind to the value in the array I'm facing some problems. The value is not binding properly when the user inputs something to the text input.

I tried running changeDetection after updating the array but didn't help.

IN this code example below am generating input element while clicking on the add button using a data array of string value "test". [ngModel] of input is binding to the value inside Array. so I expect all input to have value as "test".

But when we try entering some value into the input and then clicking on the add button, the generated input does not bind to the value in the array.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uywkxr

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <input
      *ngFor="let d of data;let i = index;trackBy:trackByfn" 
      type="text"
      [ngModel]="data[i]"
    > 
    <br/><br/>
    data: {{data|json}}
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  data = ['test'];  
  onAdd() {  
    this.data.push('test');
  }
  trackByfn = (index) => index;
}
```

Comment: You have missed two way binding of your data `[(ngModel)]="data[i]"`

Comment: Can we do it without two way binding? I don't want the input to modify the data, just want one way update. All inputs need to have value in array on clicking 'add' button. Doesn't One way binding work like that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `[ngModel]` to `[(ngModel)]` to make a Two-way Data Binding.

More about angular data binding: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <input 
      *ngFor="let d of data;let i = index;trackBy:trackByfn" 
      type="text"
      [(ngModel)]="data[i]"
    /> 
    <br/><br/>
    data: {{data|json}}
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  data = ['test'];  
  onAdd() {  
    this.data.push('test');
  }
  trackByfn = (index) => index;
}
```

**Update**: Using Form Group

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>
    <div [formGroup]="form" *ngFor="let f of fields">
      <input type="text" [formControlName]="f" /> 
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let f of fields">
      {{form.controls[f].value}}
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    test: new FormControl('test')
  });
  fields = ['test'];
  onAdd() {
    const length = this.fields.length;
    this.fields.push('test'+length);
    this.form.addControl('test'+length, new FormControl('test'));
  } // length to dynamically name the field
}
```

*Note*: Don't forget to add `ReactiveFormsModule`in your imports dependencies in `app.module.ts`

I forked your stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2t157s

Comment: Is it possible to do it without two way binding? as I don't want to actually update the data by binding. In my original senario data is coming from other source. I'm using ngrx and getting data from selector.

Comment: Updated my answer using FormGroup instead of two way binding.

Answer (score 0):

> Working Example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztonjq).

**This is two way binding syntax--->`[(ngModel)]`**
keep variable to get new value

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `

    <br/><br/>
    <input *ngFor="let d of data;let i = index;trackBy:trackByfn" 
    type="text" [value]="data[i]" [(ngModel)]="dataarray"> 
     <button (click)="onAdd(data[i])">Add</button>
    <br/><br/>
    data: {{data|json}}
      `,
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent  {

       data = ["ssdsdsd"];
       datatosave:any;  
      onAdd(data1) {  
        this.data.push(this.datatosave);

      }
      trackByfn = (index) => index;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `@ViewChildren` directive. In the `onAdd()` the last element of `inputs` is pushed to `data[]`. Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/view-children-13) for the same.

Code:

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, ElementRef, 
         QueryList, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <button (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>
  <br/><br/>
  <input #inputRef type="text" 
  *ngFor="let d of data; let i = index; trackBy:trackByfn"> 
  <br/><br/>
  data: {{data | json}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  data = ['test'];

  @ViewChildren("inputRef") inputs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  onAdd() {
    let domElement = this.inputs.last as ElementRef;
    this.data.push(domElement.nativeElement.value);
  }

}
```

More on the `@ViewChildren` can be found in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#viewchildren).